# How and when to use 「そうですね」？

Tags: word-choice, translation, words, meaning, register

I only know the 2 meanings of it as follow:

1. Use when thinking - no meaning
2. Use to agree with others - the meaning is like "yes, I think so"

What else and what situation can it be used?

If someone ask me "これはあなたの財布ですか？”, Can I answer 「そうですね」?
Is it strange?　or Is it better to answer without 「ね」?

Comment: It is better without ね.  With ね, it does not sound like an answer about your own thing.  But I wonder why.

Comment: そうですね is an answer to きょうはいい天気ですね ("Today is nice, isn't it?"), and expresses agreeing with opinions/feelings of others. そうです is answer to これはあなたの財布ですか ("Is this your wallet?").

Answer (score 6):

In your example:

> これはあなたの財布ですか

そうですね doesn't work.

The ね at the end gives a feeling of asking for a confirmation (As in *yes, right?*)

At the beginning of a sentence ね is used to get someone's attention or (if followed by an interrogation mark) to ask for confirmation.

Just use そうです instead.

Answer (score 6):

そうですね can also be if you are thinking about the response or even if you are disagreeing with a statement.

```
最近円高って大変だと思わないですか
そうですね。大丈夫だと思いますよ。
```

It is used by a listener to acknowledge something you said, but not necessarily agree with it. Like, 'I get that you think that, but I completely disagree.'